# Nodejs dosent invite the user to group (Steam)

Tags: node.js, steam, steambot

The problem is if user add the bot, the bot will accept but won't invite to the steam group (No error)

```
client.on("friendRelationship", (steamid, relationship) => {
    community.getSteamUser(steamid, function(err, user){
    if(err){
       return console.log("["+getTime()+"] " +err);
    } else{       
        if (relationship === 2) {
            client.addFriend(steamid);
        } else if (relationship === 3) {
            if (CONFIG.INVITETOGROUPID) {
                client.inviteToGroup(steamid, CONFIG.INVITETOGROUPID);
            }
            client.chatMessage(steamid, CONFIG.message);
        }
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: which steam apis or npm steam libraries are you using?  Where is community defined?

Comment: community = new SteamCommunity();